# Keras: "RuntimeError: Failed to import pydot." after installing graphviz and pydot

Tags: python, graphviz, theano, keras, pydot

I'm using Anaconda Python 2.7 on windows 10

I was planning on doing Keras visualization so (whilst spyder was open) I opened the Anaconda command prompt and pip installed graphviz and pydot. Now when I try run the following:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
```

or any sort of "from keras." ,  I get the error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name gof
```

I have uninstalled and reinstalled Keras, Graphviz and pydot. i am using the development version of theano. I cannot find a fix.

**P.S**

If I uninstall graphviz and pydot, keras works again

**EDIT**

After uninstalling anaconda and reinstalling it including theano, keras, **graphviz and pydot** I now get the following error:

```
from keras.utils.visualize_util import plot

Using Theano backend.
Using gpu device 0: GeForce GTX 970M (CNMeM is disabled, cuDNN not available)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-65016ddab3cd>", line 1, in <module>
  from keras.utils.visualize_util import plot

  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\visualize_util.py", line  8, in <module>
  raise RuntimeError('Failed to import pydot. You must install pydot'

RuntimeError: Failed to import pydot. You must install pydot and graphviz  for `pydotprint` to work.
```

I used `pip install graphviz` and `pip install git+https://github.com/nlhepler/pydot.git`

Comment: Can you paste the complete error message from python?

Comment: Keras is now running again. But without the packages Graphviz and Pydot installed. When I tried uninstalling them earlier on my python crashed every time I opened it, which is why I'm too afraid to attempt re-installation of either of the packages. Could it be that one of them gets in the way of Keras?

Comment: With your edit, the question has now changed significantly, you should edit the title to reflect the new question.

Comment: I've answered similar question with step-by-step debugging technique at https://stackoverflow.com/a/47433183/1074998

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The error message is a bit misleading, as you can see [here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/utils/visualize_util.py#L7). The problem is that graphviz is not installed.

But you mention that graphviz was installed using pip. This is also misleading, since that graphviz package is just a python wrapper, and the [graphviz binaries](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/download/) have to be installed separately for the python wrapper to work.

Comment: I had similar issue. The only answer that solved my problem among many similar questions. Thanks!

Comment: thanks, the error message is misleading, when sudo yum install graphviz, it fixed

Comment: sudo apt-get install graphviz

Comment: In Windows 10, download the .msi installer from http://www.graphviz.org/Download_windows.php, run it. When installation is complete make sure that you add the path to the GraphViz binaries (C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin) to the windows PATH variable. You may need to restart your Python kernel for it to pick up the path properly.

Comment: run `apt-get install graphviz` on debian  `yum install graphviz` on CentOS

Comment: for windows just run, `conda install graphviz` and `pip install pydot`

Answer (score 10):

If you are using an Anaconda environment, you'd better install `pydotplus` and `graphviz` via `conda install`.

```
conda install graphviz
conda install pydotplus
```

Note:
You'd better update your Keras to the newest version (2.0.9+), it can automatically check and choose which one of `pydotplus`,`pydot-ng`,`pydot` to be used. `pydot-ng` has been unmaintained for a long time, and it only supports py3.4- and py2.7.

Answer (score 4):

What I did is followed.

```
import keras
import pydotplus
from keras.utils.vis_utils import model_to_dot
keras.utils.vis_utils.pydot = pydot

plot_model(your_model_name, to_file='model.png')
```

That's worked for me.
On mac Anaconda python=3.6.8

Comment: Extended view `plot_model(model, to_file='model_plot.png', show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True)`

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I am using Anaconda python on Ubuntu. but it seems that Keras uses system's python not the Anaconda python. Initially,  I installed pydot and graphviz using conda. When I installed pydot and graphviz in system's python(using /usr/bin/pip install pydot) it worked fine.

Comment: But I am on Windows and use Anaconda. I understand there is one python in my case. Even then it fails. Any ideas on what could be wrong ?

Answer (score 3):

Keras 2.0.6 looks for pydot-ng (better maintained) and then if it's not found, falls back on pydot. I resolved this issue by installing pydot-ng from [source](https://github.com/pydot/pydot-ng).

Answer (score 2):

Install graphviz by brew in osx `brew install graphviz`, for ubuntu use `apt-get install graphviz`, do not need to install graphviz by pip.

Comment: That's hardly an answer for the question.

Comment: @phd Did you try it?  "pip install pydot"   then "brew install graphviz" and it will work

Comment: Atleast for Ubuntu machines, this worked like a charm

Comment: If it still does not work, do "pip install pydot-ng"

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem with my Keras (without anaconda). I have solved my problem using this way

```
sudo pip install pydot
sudo pip install graphviz
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gviz-adm/graphviz-dev
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install graphviz-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

1)Conda install graphviz
2)pip install graphviz
3)pip install pydot
then:

`import os
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\envs\\tensorflow\\Library\\bin\\graphviz'`

Answer (score 0):

For Anaconda on Mac:

To install this package with conda run:

`conda install -c anaconda graphviz`

Answer (score 0):

1. Install `graphviz` to the system. Download the package from [here](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/download/), or on Mac:

   ```
   brew install graphviz
   ```
2. Install python pydot-ng and graphviz wrapper.

   ```
   pip install pydot-ng graphviz
   conda install -c anaconda pydot-ng #Anaconda user
   ```
3. Use `pydot-ng` in your code

   ```
   import pydot_ng as pydot
   ```
4. If Keras visualization utils still uses pydot, try to change `import pydot` to `import pydot_ng as pydot` in `visualize_util.py`

Answer (score 0):

The below works inside a jupyter notebook runing in a `jupyter/tensorflow-notebook` docker container.

```
!conda install -y graphviz pydotplus

import pydotplus
import keras.utils
keras.utils.vis_utils.pydot = pydotplus
keras.utils.plot_model(your_model_name, to_file='model.png', show_shapes=True)
```

You need to tell keras to use *pydotplus*

Answer (score 0):

it is nothing related to pydot or graphviz if you have installed via pip.

You should go download [graphviz brinary](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/download/) and install.

Don't forget adding the bin folder into your PATH: C:/Program Files (x86)/Graphviz2.38/bin/

And after that to close and reopen your console.

Answer (score 0):

After installing pydot and graphviz and adding graphviz to the path, you can **restart** the IDE or terminal. [see here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50996574/error-when-trying-to-use-keras-utils-plot-model/67278641#67278641)