# "Failed to import pydot" throws in kerasR

Tags: r, keras

I use the package keras under R and I would like to know if there was a command like python with plot_model () which allows to display its neuron network

```
library(keras)
```

for example I would like to display this neural network under R

```
  model <- keras_model_sequential()
  model %>%
    layer_dense(units = 5, input_shape = 2) %>%
    layer_activation("relu") %>%
    layer_dense(units = 1)
```

I install package kerasR for use the function plot_model(), but i have this error.

```
> library(kerasR)
> plot_model(model)

Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  ImportError: Failed to import pydot. You must install pydot and graphviz for `pydotprint` to work.

Detailed traceback: 
  File "C:\Users\Idriss\ANACON~1\envs\R-TENS~1\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\vis_utils.py", line 131, in plot_model
    dot = model_to_dot(model, show_shapes, show_layer_names, rankdir)
  File "C:\Users\Idriss\ANACON~1\envs\R-TENS~1\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\vis_utils.py", line 52, in model_to_dot
    _check_pydot()
  File "C:\Users\Idriss\ANACON~1\envs\R-TENS~1\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\vis_utils.py", line 27, in _check_pydot
    raise ImportError('Failed to import pydot. You must install pydot'
```

I'm use windows 10 64 bits, i use RStudio with Anaconda

---

In [4] pydot.Dot.create(pydot.Dot())

```
Out[4]: b"%!PS-Adobe-3.0\r\n%%Creator: graphviz version 2.38.0 (20140413.2041)\r\n%%Title: G\r\n%%Pages: (atend)\r\n%%BoundingBox: (atend)\r\n%%EndComments\r\nsave\r\n%%BeginProlog\r\n/DotDict 200 dict def\r\nDotDict begin\r\n\r\n/setupLatin1 {\r\nmark\r\n/EncodingVector 256 array def\r\n EncodingVector 0\r\n\r\nISOLatin1Encoding 0 255 getinterval putinterval\r\nEncodingVector 45 /hyphen put\r\n\r\n% Set up ISO Latin 1 character encoding\r\n/starnetISO {\r\n        dup dup findfont dup length dict begin\r\n        { 1 index /FID ne { def }{ pop pop } ifelse\r\n        } forall\r\n        /Encoding EncodingVector def\r\n        currentdict end definefont\r\n} def\r\n/Times-Roman starnetISO def\r\n/Times-Italic starnetISO def\r\n/Times-Bold starnetISO def\r\n/Times-BoldItalic starnetISO def\r\n/Helvetica starnetISO def\r\n/Helvetica-Oblique starnetISO def\r\n/Helvetica-Bold starnetISO def\r\n/Helvetica-BoldOblique starnetISO def\r\n/Courier starnetISO def\r\n/Courier-Oblique starnetISO def\r\n/Courier-Bold starnetISO def\r\n/Courier-BoldOblique starnetISO def\r\ncleartomark\r\n} bind def\r\n\r\n%%BeginResource: procset graphviz 0 0\r\n/coord-font-family /Times-Roman def\r\n/default-font-family /Times-Roman def\r\n/coordfont coord-font-family findfont 8 scalefont def\r\n\r\n/InvScaleFactor 1.0 def\r\n/set_scale {\r\n       dup 1 exch div /InvScaleFactor exch def\r\n       scale\r\n} bind def\r\n\r\n% styles\r\n/solid { [] 0 setdash } bind def\r\n/dashed { [9 InvScaleFactor mul dup ] 0 setdash } bind def\r\n/dotted { [1 InvScaleFactor mul 6 InvScaleFactor mul] 0 setdash } bind def\r\n/invis {/fill {newpath} def /stroke {newpath} def /show {pop newpath} def} bind def\r\n/bold { 2 setlinewidth } bind def\r\n/filled { } bind def\r\n/unfilled { } bind def\r\n/rounded { } bind def\r\n/diagonals { } bind def\r\n/tapered { } bind def\r\n\r\n% hooks for setting color \r\n/nodecolor { sethsbcolor } bind def\r\n/edgecolor { sethsbcolor } bind def\r\n/graphcolor { sethsbcolor } bind def\r\n/nopcolor {pop pop pop} bind def\r\n\r\n/beginpage {\t% i j npages\r\n\t/npages exch def\r\n\t/j exch def\r\n\t/i exch def\r\n\t/str 10 string def\r\n\tnpages 1 gt {\r\n\t\tgsave\r\n\t\t\tcoordfont setfont\r\n\t\t\t0 0 moveto\r\n\t\t\t(\\() show i str cvs show (,) show j str cvs show (\\)) show\r\n\t\tgrestore\r\n\t} if\r\n} bind def\r\n\r\n/set_font {\r\n\tfindfont exch\r\n\tscalefont setfont\r\n} def\r\n\r\n% draw text fitted to its expected width\r\n/alignedtext {\t\t\t% width text\r\n\t/text exch def\r\n\t/width exch def\r\n\tgsave\r\n\t\twidth 0 gt {\r\n\t\t\t[] 0 setdash\r\n\t\t\ttext stringwidth pop width exch sub text length div 0 text ashow\r\n\t\t} if\r\n\tgrestore\r\n} def\r\n\r\n/boxprim {\t\t\t\t% xcorner ycorner xsize ysize\r\n\t\t4 2 roll\r\n\t\tmoveto\r\n\t\t2 copy\r\n\t\texch 0 rlineto\r\n\t\t0 exch rlineto\r\n\t\tpop neg 0 rlineto\r\n\t\tclosepath\r\n} bind def\r\n\r\n/ellipse_path {\r\n\t/ry exch def\r\n\t/rx exch def\r\n\t/y exch def\r\n\t/x exch def\r\n\tmatrix currentmatrix\r\n\tnewpath\r\n\tx y translate\r\n\trx ry scale\r\n\t0 0 1 0 360 arc\r\n\tsetmatrix\r\n} bind def\r\n\r\n/endpage { showpage } bind def\r\n/showpage { } def\r\n\r\n/layercolorseq\r\n\t[\t% layer color sequence - darkest to lightest\r\n\t\t[0 0 0]\r\n\t\t[.2 .8 .8]\r\n\t\t[.4 .8 .8]\r\n\t\t[.6 .8 .8]\r\n\t\t[.8 .8 .8]\r\n\t]\r\ndef\r\n\r\n/layerlen layercolorseq length def\r\n\r\n/setlayer {/maxlayer exch def /curlayer exch def\r\n\tlayercolorseq curlayer 1 sub layerlen mod get\r\n\taload pop sethsbcolor\r\n\t/nodecolor {nopcolor} def\r\n\t/edgecolor {nopcolor} def\r\n\t/graphcolor {nopcolor} def\r\n} bind def\r\n\r\n/onlayer { curlayer ne {invis} if } def\r\n\r\n/onlayers {\r\n\t/myupper exch def\r\n\t/mylower exch def\r\n\tcurlayer mylower lt\r\n\tcurlayer myupper gt\r\n\tor\r\n\t{invis} if\r\n} def\r\n\r\n/curlayer 0 def\r\n\r\n%%EndResource\r\n%%EndProlog\r\n%%BeginSetup\r\n14 default-font-family set_font\r\n1 setmiterlimit\r\n% /arrowlength 10 def\r\n% /arrowwidth 5 def\r\n\r\n% make sure pdfmark is harmless for PS-interpreters other than Distiller\r\n/pdfmark where {pop} {userdict /pdfmark /cleartomark load put} ifelse\r\n% make '<<' and '>>' safe on PS Level 1 devices\r\n/languagelevel where {pop languagelevel}{1} ifelse\r\n2 lt {\r\n    userdict (<<) cvn ([) cvn load put\r\n    userdict (>>) cvn ([) cvn load put\r\n} if\r\n\r\n%%EndSetup\r\nsetupLatin1\r\n%%Page: 1 1\r\n%%PageBoundingBox: 36 36 44 44\r\n%%PageOrientation: Portrait\r\n0 0 1 beginpage\r\ngsave\r\n36 36 8 8 boxprim clip newpath\r\n1 1 set_scale 0 rotate 40 40 translate\r\nendpage\r\nshowpage\r\ngrestore\r\n%%PageTrailer\r\n%%EndPage: 1\r\n%%Trailer\r\n%%Pages: 1\r\n%%BoundingBox: 36 36 44 44\r\nend\r\nrestore\r\n%%EOF\r\n"
```

Comment: The error message clearly stated that you need install `pydot` and `graphviz` first. Run `pip install pydot` and `pip install graphviz` (Or `pip3`, depends on your python version) should do the trick.

Comment: Similar questions at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36886711/keras-runtimeerror-failed-to-import-pydot-after-installing-graphviz-and-pyd, https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/3210 ,and https://github.com/Theano/Theano/issues/1801

Comment: Hello, i first made this command _pip install git+https://github.com/nlhepler/pydot.git_ then your and now i have this new problem i posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47397034/cant-update-anaconda-and-cant-run-rstudio , i can't run Rstudio.

Answer (score 1):

First thing first, the error:

```
  File "C:\Users\Idriss\ANACON~1\envs\R-TENS~1\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\vis_utils.py", line 52, in model_to_dot
    _check_pydot()
```

If we check the file `C:\Users\Idriss\ANACON~1\envs\R-TENS~1\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\vis_utils.py` and search for the function `_check_pydot()`:

```
def _check_pydot():
    try:
        # Attempt to create an image of a blank graph
        # to check the pydot/graphviz installation.
        pydot.Dot.create(pydot.Dot())
    except Exception:
        # pydot raises a generic Exception here,
        # so no specific class can be caught.
        raise ImportError('Failed to import pydot. You must install pydot'
                          ' and graphviz for `pydotprint` to work.')
```

This error message is lack of information since it catch ALL `exception` instead of specific execption and raise hard-coded error `ImportError(Failed to import blah blah)`.

To ensure it import the relevant `pydot`, we should also check import part in that file (Rerun `R` and `library(kerasR)` to test):

```
import os
print("hole 0")
try:
    # pydot-ng is a fork of pydot that is better maintained.
    import pydot_ng as pydot
    print("hole 1")

except ImportError:
    # pydotplus is an improved version of pydot
    try:
        print("hole 1.2")
        import pydotplus as pydot
        print("hole 2")

    except ImportError:
        # Fall back on pydot if necessary.
        try:
            print("hole 3")
            import pydot
        except ImportError:
            print("hole 4")
            pydot = None
print("hole -1: " + str(locals())) #alternative way to debug
...
```

Tips: The safer way to debug is use`repr` instead of `str`.

If you manually run python in interactive mode and do `pydot.Dot.create(pydot.Dot())`, you will find out the exact exception (below is my Linux sample):

```
xb@dnxb:~/anaconda3/envs/r-tensorflow/bin$ ./python
Python 3.6.3 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Nov 20 2017, 20:41:42) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pydot
>>> pydot.Dot()
<pydot.Dot object at 0x7f7d045cdb38>
>>> pydot.Dot
<class 'pydot.Dot'>
>>> pydot.Dot.create(pydot.Dot())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/xiaobai/anaconda3/envs/r-tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pydot.py", line 1878, in create
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/home/xiaobai/anaconda3/envs/r-tensorflow/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/home/xiaobai/anaconda3/envs/r-tensorflow/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1344, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'dot': 'dot'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/xiaobai/anaconda3/envs/r-tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pydot.py", line 1883, in create
    prog=prog))
Exception: "dot" not found in path.
>>>
```

Let's print some variables used in the file `/home/xiaobai/anaconda3/envs/r-tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pydot.py` before the line 1878:

```
try:
    print("env: " + str(env))
    print("cmdline: " + str(cmdline))
    print("tmp_dir: " + str(tmp_dir))
    p = subprocess.Popen(
        cmdline,
        env=env,
        cwd=tmp_dir,
        shell=False,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
except OSError as e:
    if e.errno == os.errno.ENOENT:
        raise Exception(
            '"{prog}" not found in path.'.format(
                prog=prog))
    else:
        raise
```

Restart your python interpreter, rerun the `import pydot` and `pydot.Dot.create(pydot.Dot())`, it will shows:

```
xb@dnxb:~/anaconda3/envs/r-tensorflow/bin$ ./python
Python 3.6.3 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Nov 20 2017, 20:41:42) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pydot
>>> pydot.Dot.create(pydot.Dot())
env: {'PATH': '/home/xiaobai/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:...<My other PATH>'}
cmdline: ['dot', '-Tps', '/tmp/tmpffo17gx5']
tmp_dir: /tmp
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/xiaobai/anaconda3/envs/r-tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pydot.py", line 1881, in create
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

So basically what it does is run the command `dot -Tps /tmp/tmpffo17gx5` but failed due to `dot` command not found.

In Linux, it will suggest run `sudo apt install graphviz` to install `dot` if I run the command manually in terminal:

```
xb@dnxb:~/anaconda3/envs/r-tensorflow/bin$ dot
The program 'dot' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install graphviz
xb@dnxb:~/anaconda3/envs/r-tensorflow/bin$ sudo apt install graphviz
...
```

Run `dot -Tps /tmp/tmpffo17gx5` will success now:

```
xb@dnxb:~/anaconda3/envs/r-tensorflow/bin$ dot -Tps /tmp/tmpffo17gx5 
%!PS-Adobe-3.0
%%Creator: graphviz version 2.38.0 (20140413.2041)
%%Title: G
%%Pages: (atend)
%%BoundingBox: (atend)
%%EndComments
save
%%BeginProlog
/DotDict 200 dict def
DotDict begin
...
```

Restart R session, no more error:

```
> plot_model(model)
>
```

This `sudo apt install graphviz` is for Linux, but I hope this answer help you debug the error in Windows.

Comment: Hello,  I did not understand well, in files **vis_utils.py** , **anaconda3/envs/r-tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pydot.py** ,  I change all the str in  repr ?

Comment: @problème0123 You don't have to change unless you get error of that line. The `print()` lines such as `print("env: " + str(env))` is added by me, which `str()`is a function to print variable for debug. `str()` works in most cases, but it might encounter encoding issue,  while `repr()` function has no such issue.

Comment: Hello, i do the command **pydot.Dot.create(pydot.Dot())** in Spyder(python 3.6), i edited my first post for show the result.

Comment: @problème0123  `plot_model(model)` still get the error `'Failed to import pydot. You must install pydot'` ? You don't have to test this if no more error when do `plot_model(model)`.

Answer (score 1):

You should install the Python libraries:

```
pip install pydot graphviz
```

And also you need to download the graphviz binaries, and these are not installed with Python.

On Ubuntu you can install them with apt:

```
apt-get install -y graphviz libgraphviz-dev
```

On osX with brew:

```
brew install graphviz
```

For Windows and other operating systems, the instructions can be found at http://www.graphviz.org/