# Can't update anaconda and can't run rstudio : R Error: running command status 127

Tags: anaconda, rstudio

I install graphviz and pydot from the anaconda console

```
conda install graphviz
pip install git+https://github.com/nlhepler/pydot.git
```

And i I was no longer able to launch Anaconda, so I type these commands

```
conda install anaconda-navigator
```

I can launch Ananconda but I am offered to update the software, i click yes and i have this message

```
C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\python.exe C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py 
install --yes --json --force-pscheck --name root anaconda-navigator=1.6.4: HTTP 000
CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/win-64/repodata.json.bz2><br>
Elapsed: -<br><br>An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.<br>HTTP errors are 
often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.<br>ConnectionError(
MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='repo.continuum.io', port=443): Max retries exceeded 
with url: /pkgs/main/win-64/repodata.json.bz2 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<
requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000000005F6B940>: 
Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',))",),)<br>
```

When i want to run RStudio i have this message

```
rstudio.exe - The procedure entry point was not found
?toLocal8Bit@QString@@QEGBA?AVQByteArray@@XY can not be found in the dynamic link library 
C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\Library\bin\rstudio.exe
```

---

---

```
library(tensorflow)
install_tensorflow()  # success i have now i folder *r-tensorflow* in *C:\Anaconda3\envs\r-tensorflow*
```

**sessionInfo()**

```
R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=French_France.1252  LC_CTYPE=French_France.1252    LC_MONETARY=French_France.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                  
[5] LC_TIME=French_France.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] httr_1.3.1      compiler_3.4.2  R6_2.2.2        tools_3.4.2     withr_2.0.0     curl_3.0        yaml_2.1.14    
 [8] memoise_1.1.0   git2r_0.19.0    digest_0.6.12   devtools_1.13.4
```

**reticulate::conda_list()**

```
          name                                        python
1 r-tensorflow C:\\Anaconda3\\envs\\r-tensorflow\\python.exe
```

**reticulate::py_config()**

```
python:         C:\ANACON~1\python.exe
libpython:      C:/ANACON~1/python36.dll
pythonhome:     C:\ANACON~1
version:        3.6.3 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Oct 15 2017, 03:27:45) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
Architecture:   64bit
numpy:          C:\ANACON~1\lib\site-packages\numpy
numpy_version:  1.13.3

python versions found: 
 C:\ANACON~1\python.exe
 C:\Anaconda3\envs\r-tensorflow\python.exe
```

I reuninstall Rtools, in my system path: Path

- C:\Anaconda3\R\bin
- C:\Anaconda3\R\bin\x64
- C:\Anaconda3\Scripts
- C:\Rtools\bin
- C:\Rtools\mingw_32\bin

Comment: Can you access https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/win-64/ in web browser ?

Comment: yes i can access the page pkgs/main/win-64, i uninstall anaconda, and reinstall as well as rstudio now when i try to install a package i get this error : _Downloading GitHub repo rstudio/reticulate@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/rstudio/reticulate/zipball/master
Error: running command '"C:/ANACON~1/R/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD config CC' had status 127_  (I reinstall RTools)

Comment: See this https://github.com/rstudio/tensorflow/issues/144 , https://github.com/rstudio/keras/issues/46 , and https://github.com/catavallejos/BASiCS/issues/9

Comment: Hello, I looked at the three posts, I made all the proposed commands and I still have the same problem, i edit my post to show you the order results.
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/rstudio/reticulate/zipball/master
Error: running command '"C:/ANACON~1/R/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD config CC' had status 127

Comment: Are you able to run `C:/ANACON~1/R/bin/x64/R --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD config CC` from cmd ?

Comment: when u  say cmd do you mean anaconda prompt or windows terminal ? I tried both: **windows terminal i have this resultat** : `C:/ANACON~1/R/../Library/mingw-w64/bin/gcc` and **on anaconda prompt i have this**: `bash.exe: warning: could not find /tmp, please create!
C:\ANACON~1\R/bin/config.sh: line 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 313: make: command not found`

Comment: See this https://github.com/cjgb/rPython-win/issues/17 , ("missconfiguration of the cygwin path"). I think you better file a report on github.

Comment: `R --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD config CC` should run without error. Note that simply run `R` without parameter in command prompt(I don't test in windows, but better do this in anaconda cmd) should able go into R interactive mode.

Comment: From what I understand it is due to the fact that I anonca 64 bits? If I install anaconda 32 bits it will be ok? i do the command in the anaconda prompt > r: *R --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD config CC* i have the result `Error: unexpected symbol in "R --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD"`

Comment: You shouldn't run the `R` command in `> r`, the `R` command should try outside of R interactive mode.