# incompatible version of decorator during installation graphviz in windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, plot, keras, graphviz, python-decorators

I want to use plot model to see a DNN model:

```
plot_model(model, to_file='model_plot.png', show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True)
```

I saw that c:\users\lb\anaconda30\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\vis_utils.py", line 29, in _check_pydot
    '`pydot` failed to call GraphViz.'
OSError: `pydot` failed to call GraphViz.Please install GraphViz (https://www.graphviz.org/) and ensure that its executables are in the $PATH.

So, I want to install graphviz in anacoda windows 10 but I saw the following error. How I can solve this problem?

```
>pip install graphviz
```

Requirement already satisfied: graphviz in c:\users\lb\anaconda30\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages (0.8.3)
networkx 2.1 has requirement decorator>=4.1.0, but you'll have decorator 4.0.11 which is incompatible.

Comment: You are asking the wrong question, the problem has already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36886711/keras-runtimeerror-failed-to-import-pydot-after-installing-graphviz-and-pyd/

Comment: Thanks Matias,I saw this but this does not work! The problem is what I have written in the title of question: networkx 2.1 has requirement decorator>=4.1.0, but you'll have decorator 4.0.11 which is incompatible. I do not know how I could make them compatible!