# Jupyter w/ Tensorflow pydotprint not found error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, jupyter, pydot

I'm using the tensorflow docker image run this way:

```
docker run -it --rm -v $(realpath ~/Documents/notebooks):/tf/notebooks -p 8888:8888 tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-py3-jupyter
```

I'm trying to generate dot files / plots of the model I've made, but all of the functions say:

> Failed to import pydot. You must install pydot and graphviz for
>   `pydotprint` to work.

At the top of my notebook, I have:

```
!pip install pydot
!pip install graphviz
```

And I'm using Tensorflow 2.0.0

How do I get this to work?  Everything I've seen says to install those modules with pip.  I've done that, but it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: According to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47119931/6862189) , you can solve it

Answer (score 1):

Use

`conda install graphviz`

`conda install pydot`

can solve the problem.

It seems like that `graphviz` is a system level package which should be installed by `conda` or `apt/yum/brew`